# Checking two identical values inside a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm doing a function that receives a map (the map contains string as key and int as value) and throws an exception if it finds that a value is repeated.  My first try was this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int>::iterator mapIt;

void mapcheck(std::map<std::string, int> &saidMap){

    for (mapIt it = saidMap.begin(); it != saidMap.end(); it++){

       try{
          for (mapIt at = saidMap.begin(); at != saidMap.end(); at++){
               if (at == it)
                  throw Myexception();
          }

    }
      catch (Myexception &e){
             std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
          }
       }
```

But obviously that will just throw the exception at every run. Is there a function of map that allows to compare the values inside??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by identical. If you're talking about the keys they can never be identical in a map by definition.

Comment: If you have a lot of values to test, a better solution (time-wise) would be to attempt to place the values into a std::set<int> in stead of a double for-loop.

Comment: consider taking `saidMap` by const reference: then the compiler will potentially be able to generate better code, and it will give an error if you accidentally write something that would modify the map. (You'll need to use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator` also).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `try...catch` inside the `mapcheck` function. This is just `goto` hidden behind some exception syntax, and also the caller has no way of knowing whether there was an exception or not. Surely you intended the function to `throw` so the exception propagates up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative to the code you wrote.  If you are not limited by memory, another solution is to use a `std::set<int>` as a "test container'.  The `std::set::insert()` function can be used to test for a value instead of hand-rolling an inner loop.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int>::iterator mapIt;

void mapcheck(std::map<std::string, int> &saidMap)
{
    std::set<int> testSet;
    for (mapIt it = saidMap.begin(); it != saidMap.end(); ++it)
    {
        try 
        {
           if ( !testSet.insert(it->second).second )
              throw Myexception();
        }
        catch (Myexception &e)
        {  
           std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; 
        }
    }
}
```

The `std::set::insert` function attempts to insert a value into the set, and if not successful, returns a `std::pair` with a "second" value of `false`.

The advantage of this solution as opposed to the double nested loop is that the lookup time for a `set` is logarithmic.

So for example, if there are 100,000 ints already in the set, it takes at most 16 comparisons to determine if a value is in or not in the set.  Using the double nested for loop, you have at most 100,000 values to compare.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard §23.4.4.1: *A [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) is an associative container that supports **unique keys** (contains at most one of each key value).*

Furthermore, in the `if` statement you are comparing `at` against `it` which are iterators and it's almost always guaranteed that they are not equal. Thus, the loop is never going to `throw`.

If you want a mapping with multiple keys use [`multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/).

### Update:

If you want to compare the mapped values of your `map` then you should change your `if` condition to the one below:

```
if (at->second == it->second)
   throw Myexception();
```

Comment: Not trying to compare the keys (string) but the values (int), sorry if i didn't make it clear enough.